# Why gcc does not give a warning or error when invalid mode is used in fopen()?

Tags: c, gcc, file-io, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am practicing some practice questions in FILE IO in C. Below is one of the programs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char fname[]="poem.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen ( fname, "tr");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("Unable to open file...\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    while((ch =fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
            printf("%c",ch);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in the statement

```
  fp = fopen ( fname, "tr");
```

The mode "tr" is not a valid mode (as I understand). I was expecting gcc to give an error (or a warning) while compiling the above program. However, gcc does not give any error (or warning) while compiling it.

However, as expected, when i run the program it exits printing "Unable to open file..." which means fopen() returned NULL , because there was error while opening file.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Unable to open file...
-bash-4.1$
```

(The file poem.txt exists so this is because of the invalid mode given to fopen(). I checked by changing the mode to "r" and it works fine displaying the content of "poem.txt")

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
THis is a poem.

-bash-4.1$
```

I was expecting gcc to give an error (or warning) message for the invalid mode.

Why gcc does not give any error (or warning) for this ?

Comment: Why would it?  It's a valid call to an external function.  The "tr" is a string parameter, as required by the function declaration.  Just because the underlying OS refused to accept a set of options at run time doesn't mean that the compiler can detect that at compile time.

Comment: @MartinJames Got you !!!I was expecting too much  from the compiler (gcc) .

Comment: @MartinJames: As another comment already pointed out, gcc can and does warn about incorrect format string arguments to `printf`. It can do so because `printf`, like `fopen`, is a standard library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Undefined Behavior:

Per Annex J.2 "Undefined Behavior", it is UDB if:

> —The string pointed to by the mode argument in a call to the fopen function does not exactly match one of the specified character sequences (7.19.5.3).

Although Annex J is informative, looking at §7.19.5.3:

> /3 The argument mode points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Basically, the compiler can blow you off here - a standard library function name (and behavior) can be used outside of the inclusion of a standard header (for example, non-standard extensions, completely user-defined behavior, etc.).  The Standard specifies what a conforming library implementation shall include and how it shall behave, but does not require you to use that standard library (or define behavior for a specific implementation explicitly specified as UDB territory: at this point, if your parameter types match it's a legal function call).

A really good `lint` utility might help you here.

Answer (score 2):

the compiler doesn't check what you do, it only checks the syntax.

However, at run time, if the code is written like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char fname[]="poem.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    fp = fopen ( fname, "tr");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror( "fopen for poem.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while((ch =fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
            printf("%c",ch);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

then a proper error message is output:

...$ ./untitled

fopen for poem.txt failed: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

How is the compiler supposed to know what the valid arguments for a function are?

To do it you'd be building too much knowledge in the compiler - it would have to recognize functions and their parameters by name. What if you want to override the function? What if different modes are valid on different platforms?

Comment: Exactly.  The parameter types match, so it gets compiled.  If anything could reject the call, it would have to be the linker, and that is not going to happen in this case either:)

Comment: The compiler vendor has access to the language standard, so it can choose to implement warnings or errors accordingly.  gcc already gives warnings for incorrect `printf` format strings, which people seem to generally think is a good idea.

Comment: C functions are called "functions", not "methods".

Answer (score 0):

In Windows programming, `"tr"` <strike>is a valid mode</strike> is not a valid mode, although `"rt"` [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx). The `t` means text and the `r` means read.  (If you are using `gcc` and linking to MS's C runtime then you will be able to use this).

However you still don't see `t` very often because it is the default and therefore redundant;  the other option for this setting is `b` meaning *binary*. But MS do seem to explicitly use `t` in their examples to make it clear that translation is intended.

The behaviour of *text mode* and *binary mode* for a stream is implementation-defined, although the intent is that *binary mode* reads the characters exactly as they appear on disk, and *text mode* may perform translations relevant to text processing; most famously, converting `\r\n` in MS text files to `\n` in your program.

Comment: Yea, "rt" is a valid mode in windows. Is "tr" treated same as "rt" ? But as I was compiling this code and runing in Linux I was sure "tr" is not a valid mode here because i saw man fopen and in modes, it was mentioned that 'b' will be supported to maintain back compatibility (although that would not make any difference) however  there was no mention of 't'.

Comment: @1Byn you're right, the `t` has to come after.  Remember that `gcc` is run on multiple platforms, so it seems like a reasonable default to not give any warnings. You could always submit a patch to warn if non-standard strings are passed :)

Comment: Yes , i guess sometime soon I should try to submit the "patch" you are talking about . (Although I have no idea what that is as of now). Good suggestion though. Will keep in mind.